# Plot3D Color Bug with Large Inputs

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, mac-os-x, linux

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1**

---

Running the code:

```
c1 = 3*^-20;
c2 = 0.8*^-2;
c3 = 5*^16;
a = 1*^-9;

Plot3D[(c1 + c2 q^2) (1 - Cos[2 Pi (x - q)/a]) + (c3 q^4), {x, 0, 
  5*^-8}, {q, 0, 1*^-9}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

results in the plot

[image]

that is to say, a plot that is missing colour, or rather it colours everything black, the Roling stones style. Running the same code on my windows machine, the plot becomes coloured. My linux machine runs mathematica 11, my windows mathematica 10.

Any ideas what might cause this behaviour and more importantly how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: The bug tag has to be added by someone else if a bug is confirmed. I cannot reproduce the issue on debian. You could try downloading proprietary software for your graphics card.

Comment: Confirmed bug. It has to do with the size of the inputs. If you rescale it away from the nearly machine limit sized numbers then it is fine. Oh, and I can reproduce this on a mac.

Comment: I can't reproduce the lack of color on MMA 11.0.1 and Win7-64 with the code provided; [this is what I get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Efmjy.png).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll look into the rescaling!

Comment: Has any one solved this one? I have the same issue

Comment: @DavidVega I do not see the problem in 11.2.  11.0 and 11.1 are affected, as you can read in the question.